# how can I get bold symbols using \boldsymbol and tex4ht with MathML output?

Tags: tex4ht, mathml, boldmath

Here is a sample from a LaTeX document I want to convert to HTML.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amscd}

\begin{document}

 Some math...\newline
 Scalars: regular math font $a, x, X, \alpha, \beta, \Theta, \ldots$ \newline
 Vectors: bold math font $\boldsymbol{a}, \boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{X}, \boldsymbol{\alpha}, \boldsymbol{\beta}, \boldsymbol{\Theta}, \ldots$ \newline

\end{document}
```

This is the PDF output.
[image]

This is the `.cfg` file I'm using to convert.

```
% bold-math.cfg

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% We are generating HTML + MathML code
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml,3,charset=utf-8,notoc*,nominitoc,fonts}

% Don't output xml version tag
\Configure{VERSION}{}

% Output HTML5 doctype instead of the default for HTML4
\Configure{DOCTYPE}{\HCode{<!doctype html>\Hnewline}}

% Custom page opening
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}

% Reset <head>, aka delete all default boilerplate
\Configure{@HEAD}{}

% Setup custom <head> content
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<meta charset="utf-8" />\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/\string~gurari/TeX4ht/)" />\Hnewline}}

% Add css files
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\expandafter\csname aa:CssFile\endcsname" />\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Serif/cmun-serif.css" type="text/css" />\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<link rel="stylesheet" href="bold-math-mi.css" type="text/css" />\Hnewline}}

% Setup MathJax
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=MML_CHTML"></script>\Hnewline}}
%\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<script type="text/javascript" src="../MathJax/MathJax.js?config=MML_CHTML"></script>\Hnewline}}

% Translate \textbf, \textit and \texttt directives into <b>, <em> and <code>
\Configure{emph}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<em>}}{\HCode{</em>}}
\Configure{textbf}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<b>}}{\HCode{</b>}}
\Configure{textit}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<i>}}{\HCode{</i>}}
\Configure{texttt}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<code>}}{\HCode{</code>}}

% Translate verbatim and lstlisting blocks into <pre> elements
\ConfigureEnv{verbatim}{\HCode{<pre>}}{\HCode{</pre>}}{}{}
\ConfigureEnv{lstlisting}{\HCode{<pre>}}{\HCode{</pre>}}{}{}

% Do not set `indent`/`noindent` classes on paragraphs
\Configure{HtmlPar}
{\EndP\Tg<p>}
{\EndP\Tg<p>}
{\HCode{</p>\Hnewline}}
{\HCode{</p>\Hnewline}}

\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

This is the command I use to produce the HTML file.

```
htlatex bold-math.tex "bold-math" " -cunihtf -utf8" " -cvalidate"
```

This is the HTML I get.
[image]

As you can see, the problem is that the `\boldsymbol` is ignored in the output and that the capitol `\Theta` is in italics, rather the in normal font.
After some tweaking to the MathML code in the HTML output, I can get the following.
[image]

These are a couple of tweaks I made, for reference.
From:

```
<mi>a</mi>
<mi>Θ</mi>
```

To:

```
<mi mathvariant="bold-italic">a</mi>
<mi mathvariant="bold">Θ</mi>
```

This shows that MathJax and MathML are capable to show what I want.
I assume the problem resides in tex4ht.

Does anyone know how to fix these issues?

Comment: `\bm` (needs `\usepackage{bm}`) is recommended as a better alternative to `\boldsymbol`.  does that work?

Comment: I've read about it, but the source latex code is very messy and adding that package (that redefines the `\boldsymbol` command) breaks the compilation, both PDF and HTML. The source is written by many people and most of them use a GUI latex editor that inserts bad things like many nested `boldsymbol`, e.g. `\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{a}}}`. These nested things make `bm` infinitely loop until the max memory is reached. But `bm` doesn't complain about things like `\boldsymbol{a_{\boldsymbol{b}}`. More over, `bm` doesn't work well with simple `\boldsymbol{a}^{2}` for the HTML conversion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most straightforward way to get the bold symbols is to redefine `\boldsymbols` command to include tags which you want. Put this command to your .cfg file:

```
\renewcommand\boldsymbol[1]{\HCode{<mi mathvariant="bold-italic">}\PauseMathClass #1\EndPauseMathClass\HCode{</mi>}}
```

`\PauseMathClass` will prevent `tex4ht` from including tags based on font, you would get

```
<mi mathvariant="bold-italic"><mi 
>x</mi></mi>
```

otherwise. The resulting mathml:

```xml
<mi mathvariant="bold-italic">a</mi><mo 
class="MathClass-punc">,</mo><mi mathvariant="bold-italic">x</mi><mo 
class="MathClass-punc">,</mo><mi mathvariant="bold-italic">X</mi><mo 
class="MathClass-punc">,</mo><mi mathvariant="bold-italic">α</mi><mo 
class="MathClass-punc">,</mo><mi mathvariant="bold-italic">β</mi><mo 
class="MathClass-punc">,</mo><mi mathvariant="bold-italic">Θ</mi><mo 
class="MathClass-punc">,</mo><mo 
class="MathClass-op">…</mo>
```

The other way is to use `bm` package, as Barbara suggested. It seems that it also redefines `\boldsymbol` and it is supported by `tex4ht`, with one caveat:

[image]

```xml
<mstyle mathvariant="bold"><mi 
>a</mi></mstyle><mo 
class="MathClass-punc">,</mo><mstyle mathvariant="bold"><mi 
>x</mi></mstyle><mo 
class="MathClass-punc">,</mo><mstyle mathvariant="bold"><mi 
>X</mi></mstyle><mo 
class="MathClass-punc">,</mo><mstyle mathvariant="bold"><mi 
>α</mi></mstyle><mo 
class="MathClass-punc">,</mo><mstyle mathvariant="bold"><mi 
>β</mi></mstyle><mo 
class="MathClass-punc">,</mo><mstyle mathvariant="bold"><mi 
>Θ</mi></mstyle><mo 
class="MathClass-punc">,</mo><mo 
class="MathClass-op">…</mo></math>
```

the problem is that it seems that only bold is selected, not italic style, although there is `<mi>` element as `<mstyle>` child. I am not sure whether it is only bug in Firefox rendering, but you can easily replace these elements with your desired output using some simple regular expresssion in `make4ht` build file:

```
-- sample.mk4
local filter = require "make4ht-filter"

local htmlmatch = filter {
  function(text)
    return text:gsub('<mstyle mathvariant="bold">%s*<mi%s*>([^%<]+)</mi></mstyle>', function(symbol)
      return string.format('<mi mathvariant="bold-italic">%s</mi>', symbol)
    end)
  end
}
if mode=="draft" then
  Make:htlatex {}
else
  Make:htlatex {}
  Make:htlatex {}
  Make:htlatex {}
end
Make:match("html$", htmlmatch)
```

The regular expression is included in `htmlmatch` function. Compile with:

```
make4ht -uc bold-math.cfg -e sample.mk4 bold-math.tex
```

the resulting mathml:

```
<mi mathvariant="bold-italic">a</mi><mo 
class="MathClass-punc">,</mo><mi mathvariant="bold-italic">x</mi><mo 
class="MathClass-punc">,</mo><mi mathvariant="bold-italic">X</mi><mo 
class="MathClass-punc">,</mo><mi mathvariant="bold-italic">α</mi><mo 
class="MathClass-punc">,</mo><mi mathvariant="bold-italic">β</mi><mo 
class="MathClass-punc">,</mo><mi mathvariant="bold-italic">Θ</mi><mo 
class="MathClass-punc">,</mo><mo 
class="MathClass-op">…</mo>
```

and Firefox rendering:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I tried the first solution, to redefine the `\boldsymbol` command, and it works. I still have the problems with superscripts and subscripts. But I believe the problem is inside tex4ht and not inside the `bm` package or your solutions. For example `$\boldsymbol{\sigma}_{a}^{2}` gets converted to `<mi mathvariant="bold-italic"><msubsup><mrow>σ</mi></mrow><mrow><mi>a</mi></mrow><mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow></msubsup>` where you can see that the `mi` element is open too early, before `msubsup` and `mrow`. In fact, placing the opening `mi` element right before the sigma, fixes the MathJax display

Comment: One of a great explanation, thanks to both...

Comment: @MadyYuvi I totally forgot about this answer. I've recently added a support for `\boldsymbol` to TeX4ht, so the solution from this answer will be unnecessary sooon

Comment: @michal.h21 Thanks for the update....

Answer (score 1):

@Matteo Ipri
To workaround the unbalanced tags generated by tex4ht while super-scripting or sub-scripting the bold symbol, enclose `\boldsymbol{\sigma}` with braces. This will produce rightly balanced tags.

Instead of `$\boldsymbol{\sigma}_{a}^{2}$` use `${\boldsymbol{\sigma}}_{a}^{2}$`.